# XGBRegressor score (R2) vs. eval_metric (RMSE)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, boosting, metric

According to the [API Reference](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn), `XGBRegressor().score()` returns R2.
However, according to the [XGBoost Paramters](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) page, the default `eval_metric` for regression is RMSE.

In my understanding, scoring and using an evaluation metric is the same. So what am I missing here? Does XGBoost use different defaults for its native API and the Scikit-Learn API? Or do these two options mean something different?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any reason at all why XGBoost could not choose a different default metric than sklearn?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit strange, but $R^2$ and $RMSE$ are just functions of each other, so they are, in some sense, conveying the same information.

$$
R^2=1-\dfrac{
n\big(RMSE\big)^2
}{
\sum_{i=1}^n\big(
y_i-\bar y
\big)^2
}
$$

Some people see $R^2$ as easier to interpret. I disagree with the idea that we can liken $R^2$ to grades in school where $0.9$ is an $\text{A}$ that makes us happy and $0.5$ is an $\text{F}$ that makes us sad. Depending on the context, $R^2=0.5$ might be considered spectacular, while another situation might mean that $R^2=0.9$ is rather pedestrian performance.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> scoring and using an evaluation metric is the same

But I guess I would question this idea and suggest that, at least in a typical XGBoost workflow, the concepts behind 'scoring' and 'evaluation metric' are slightly different. But only slightly.

The **evaluation metric** is used to monitor the training process and watch for overtraining (for example). I think it does make sense for this to be something that reflects the magnitude of the error or bias, and RMSE is a good choice because it has the same units as the thing you're trying to predict.

On the other hand, **scoring** is something we do after the model is fit (it's still an evaluation metric, but in the XGBoost API, I think this is the intended role for 'scoring'). We might use the score to compare between different hyperparameter choices, or between algorithms. Personally I like RMSE for scoring too, but I know lots of people like $R^2$ and perhaps expect it. Either way, I think makes sense to use a variety of metrics in most cases.

Remember not to get fixated on scores (see [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet)) and to check the distribution of your residuals! Most people seem to forget this bit...

Comment: I thought so too at first (one is training metric, the other validation metric). But the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) says something different. The section "Learning Task Parameters" explains that the task and the metric to optimize are specified like this: `objective = 'reg:squarederror'`. And `eval_metric` is "Evaluation metrics for validation data".

Comment: Personally, I think this is as deep as two developers having their own preferred choice of validation metric.

Comment: @dipetkov Sorry, I wasn't trying to say that one of those thing is being used as the cost function during training, only that it's used for in-training validation ('how is training going and am I overfitting?'). As opposed to post-training evaluation ('how did I do?'). It's a pretty subtle distinction, and I agree that there's likely just some personal preference going into the choices of defaults for these things.